# How to achieve such kind of effect using CIImage

Tags: iphone, ios, effects, ciimage

I want to achieve following kind of effects in CIImage [iPhone] :

- Somewhat looks cartoonish
- Muscles showing dark
- And other adjustments

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using a sharp or unsharp effect, and maybe a bit of posterize. Really though you should look this up yourself. Here's a good link...
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CoreImageFilterReference/Reference/reference.html

Also, i recommend using GPUImage...
https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage

Hope this helps!!